# How to get session object from the initialization block of a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, session-variables

I have a JSP file and I need to use it to return the user stored in the session object:

Factory.jsp:

```
<%@page import="users.User"%>
<%!
public static class Factory{
    public Factory(){

    }

    public static User getUser(){
        //session.getAttribute("loggedUser"); doesn't work
        return null;
    }
}

%>

<%
//some code
%>
```

Is there a way to access the session object within the getUser() method?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: @JeevanPatil No, i'm not using frameworks

Comment: I think, this is not possible because a session object is only available in "service()" method which is only used inside <% %> tags. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171521/how-to-use-request-object-within-a-function-in-jsp

Comment: My first question is: why are you mixing java directly in jsp? It wouldn't be better to use MVC, letting these functions to control layer (servlet)? Are you able to do that? So, you should use something like ${pageContext.user} or ${Sessionscope.user} to retrieve user's data.

Answer (score -1):

You would not have to use scriptlets if you were using any framework.
Try below code :

```
<%!
    Session session = request.getSession();
%>
```

Then use session object to get variables from it.

```
<%
    User user = session.getAttribute("loggedUser");
%>
```

Comment: why downvote? Please give me reason for that ? You should leave a comment after downvoting.

Comment: I didn't put the downvote, but i'll explain you why you got it: `request.getSession()` simply doesn't work in the `<%!` block.

Comment: I downvoted. The answer is wrong, and deploying it would show that. `<%! %>` indicates class-level declarations. I was on mobile when I downvoted and commenting was more trouble than it was worth. When someone downvotes w/o comment, simply go back and check your assumptions. If the community or code disagrees with the downvote, it'll usually work itself out.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Going forward I'll take care of this. But I think it's a good thing to let someone know what was wrong.

Comment: It might be, but we live in an imperfect world, and we can't always get what we want, for a variety of reasons. Check out my two questions--explain the downvotes. Can't, because there's no *rational* reason for them: such is life.